# Counting subsets (Permutations) when certain numbers must exist

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose I have a list of $n$ numbers $\{a1,a2...an\}$, and I need to create subsets of this list with $k$ numbers, REPETITIONS ALLOWED!, and the order does matter. The number of such subsets is simply $n^k$.

But, I also need the subset to include $m$ specific numbers from the list at least once. So if, say, $m=3$, then the first 3 numbers $(a1,a2,a3)$ must exist in the subset at least once.

I have tried to subtract like this: $n^k-m*(n-1)^k$ but got wrong results.

So, what is the correct formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call $$A_i = \text{# of lists that do not contain element }i.$$
You want, by the principle of Inclusion-Exclusion, $$\text{All}-\left | \bigcup _{i=1}^mA_i\right |=\sum _{i=0}^{m}(-1)^i\binom{m}{i}(n-i)^k.$$
The problem with your formula is that you are taking too many elements out that you want to include back. For example, if $k=5,m=3,n=5$ and your list is $(a_4,a_4,a_4,a_4,a_4)$ you were taking out this element $3$ times.
It is worth noticing the connection with the problem of finding surjective functions i.e., [Stirling numbers of second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)

Comment: Your formula seems to fail when m=k. In this case, the result should be k! if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Chezi I agree with you, but the formula works for that case too. It is not obvious that it is $k!$ but it is.